# Java mysql if Table Exists

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Thanks for all the support so far in my epic battle for my learning Java with MySQL. What I want to do is check if the table exists. What currently happens is that if the database is created and the tables are created as well.
But if I run the same code, I get an error that the table already exists.

The big question is how would I check of the table exists?
Here is some code that I have worked on

```
if (tabCrea.createTable(dbDef, con, preStatement, tabStruct.getAgentDetail(), "Agent Details"))
    System.out.println("Passed Here");
else
    System.out.println("Failed Here");
```

Which calls the following

```
protected boolean createTable(DataBaseDefaults dbDef, Connection con, Statement statement, String myTableName, String tableName) {

    try {
        Class.forName(dbDef.getJdbcDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbDef.getDbAddress() + dbDef.getPortAddress() + dbDef.getDbName(), 
                dbDef.getDbUserName(), dbDef.getDbPassword());
        statement = con.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(myTableName);
        System.out.println("Table Sucessfully Created : " + tableName);
        return true;
    }
    catch (SQLException e ) {
        //Problem is caught here;
        System.out.println("An error has occured on Table Creation with Table " + tableName);
        return false;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("There was no Mysql drivers found");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and the table is defined here

```
private String agentDetail = "CREATE TABLE AgentDetail ("
    + "AgentDetailIdNo INT(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    + "Initials VARCHAR(2),"
    + "AgentDetailDate DATE,"
    + "AgentDetailCount INT(64),"
    + "PRIMARY KEY(AgentDetailIdNo)"
    + ")";
```

A humble hack would appreciate any help that is on offer.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1) if you want to preserve the table if it does exist, use [`IF NOT EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

```
private String agentDetail = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AgentDetail (" ...
```

2) if you want to delete the table and start anew, delete the table first with the [`DROP TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-table.html) statement.  To do that, run the statement

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AgentDetail
```

before the create table query (note that this will delete all of the existing data in the table)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TBL_NAME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '$this_table'  or
SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname
```

and check whether table is already exist

Answer (score 1):

The [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) API, part of the JDBC spec, is the way to do this in Java. You'll specifically want to check out the `getTables' method. This is a good class to be familiar with.

Comment: Thanks Jess,I have had a look at this, but I know that I have to know a bit more before I can appreciate it. Keith